# Custom AMI fo AWSr Opsworks fails setup phase but logs seem clean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, amazon-ami, opsworks

So I've followed through this [userguide for creating an AMI from an EBS backed Opsworks instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html#d0e15789) and it all seemed to go smoothly until I attempted to boot an instance in Opsworks from the new AMI.

[image: Setup Failed]

Here's the setup log as a gist due to it exceeding the post size limit:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hailwood/d064476a06dff214436378afea6b1930/raw/3024f52a3a93fdd47e3f72ddd4ba5960cb8ff9e2/error.log

But from what I can tell there is nothing interesting there.
However when I ssh into the instance and check out `/var/chef/runs/42bb....../chef.log` I notice it;s only contents are the follwing (I've split this over two lines for easy reading):

```
/opt/aws/opsworks/current/bin/chef_command_wrapper.sh: line 96: 
/opt/chef/bin/chef-client: No such file or directory
```

Running a `find / -name 'chef-client'` tells me that the chef-client is actually installed in `/usr/bin/chef-client` but I'm not sure that's the issue as it does appear to be successfully running chef based on the error log above.